# Why is the path of NSApplicationSupportDirectory not the same in Cocoa app and console app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, sandbox

I made a small tool and needed to access the Application Support directory of the user layer, so I created a command line project, used URLsForDirectory to get the path, and everything worked fine.
But when I create a cocoa project with a gui, the path it returns is under the Containers directory, which doesn't seem to exist.
What's causing this discrepancy? What should I do to get the ~/Library/Application Support directory in the cocoa project?

this is the code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSArray* pathes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask
    ];
    NSString* applicationSupportPath = [pathes firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Application Support:%@\n", applicationSupportPath);
}


- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

    // Update the view, if already loaded.
}


@end
```

the output is :

```
2022-10-03 22:01:23.230600+0800 TestApplicationSupportPath[49579:213899] Application Support:file:///Users/bodong/Library/Containers/com.bodong.TestApplicationSupportPath/Data/Library/Application%20Support/
```

console :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    
    NSArray* pathes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask
    ];
    NSString* applicationSupportPath = [pathes firstObject];
    NSLog(@"Application Support:%@\n", applicationSupportPath);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output is :

```
2022-10-03 22:02:09.341780+0800 TestASPCmd[49791:215344] Application Support:file:///Users/bodong/Library/Application%20Support/
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Sandbox (...Library/Containers/...) vs. non-sandbox  (...Library/Application Support/...)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I found a solution, just in the project properties, switch to Signing&Capabilities, delete the Sanbox group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just in the project properties, switch to Signing&Capabilities, delete the Sanbox group.